# Preserve new line when reading xml using C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have xml that I read it to a table cell but it seems that when there is a new line it 
change it with white space. How can I preserve my new line when I read the xml using C#.

```
var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(new XmlTextReader(Server.MapPath("NSrc.xml")),
LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace); 

foreach (var descendant in xmlDoc.Descendants("NewsItem")) 
{    
    var title = descendant.Element ("Title").Value;
    TableRow rw = new TableRow();
    TableCell cell = new TableCell();

    var title = descendant.Element("Title").Value;
    var summary = descendant.Element("Summary").Value;

    cell.Text = title;
    rw.Cells.Add(cell);
    tbl.Controls.Add(rw);

    rw = new TableRow();
    cell = new TableCell();
    cell.Text = summary;
    rw.Cells.Add(cell);
    tbl.Controls.Add(rw);
}
```

Comment: When you say "new line", do you mean a carriage return, or do you mean, in HTML, a BR element? In a HTML table, a carriage return will NOT render as a BR and the text will not appear on a new line in the browser window.

Comment: @nikki - `<br>` is indeed a HTML element, not XML.

Comment: I am reading xml file to display on aspx which is html.

Comment: So you're displaying the content in an html table and you need the text in the table cell to break where there is a newline in the XML, is that correct? If so, how exactly are you setting the text in the html from the XML? You will need to replace carriage returns with BR elements.

Comment: Correct!!! and I am taking the "title" as an example and display, I can post the whole code if needed.

Comment: cell.Text = title;     rw.Cells.Add(cell);     tbl.Controls.Add(rw);

Comment: Please post your code, as how you change a newline to a BR will depend on that. You  may need to create a new text node or set innerhtml or whatever.

Comment: I  have edit the code to show how I was reading and displaying it. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By setting PreserveWhitespace, you were trying a simple approach that "should work". For most XML reading APIs, this works exactly as you'd expect, and any newline that occurs within an element's data will be read back verbatim within your program (but beware that all other whitespace, including indentation ect will be included too).

However, the Load method, when used with an XmlReader, [ignores the Preserve setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387014.aspx). D'oh.

If you instead [Load from a Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838321.aspx), it should preserve whitespace is asked to by the LoadOptions.

(I'll leave it to others to decide whether or not preserving whitespace in this way is a good or evil approach. Encoding the newlines using CDATA would no doubt be more correct if you are in control of the source XML data. But it is an approach that will work, and I felt it only fair to let you know why it didn't work as you expected)

Comment: I have control on XML file/data. Somebody just give me how to/ with code. thanks

Comment: If I go with CDATA. can you provide the code to write to XML.

Comment: I think Henk has answered that - if you're writing the XML, then you can put a newline "\n" in the text, and encode it as CData by creating an XCData object with your string. Note that if you get the text from other sources, like a multiline edit box, then any newlines the user has entered will be in the form of \n characters, so you shouldn't need to do anything else.

Comment: <![CDATA[some text]]> is the answer! worked very well with me.

Comment: Please mark Henk's answer as "the answer" - I've possibly added useful info, but I think his is the correct solution if you have control of the source XML.

Answer (score 7):

This is proper XML behaviour, newlines don't exist in XML. Some formatters may add them (again but maybe different) on output.

> How can I preserve my new line when I read the xml

By packing your text in a CDATA element.

---

#### Edit

```
xmlDoc.Root.Add(new XCData("line1\nline2"));
```

You can retrieve this multi-line text as Root.Value

Comment: How do I pack my text in a CDATA element?

Comment: I don't think you can. Not without reading it as Text and reading/changing the XML first. Maybe XmlReader has an option to preserve formatting, I don't know.